# Aplicación web TPV en Ubuntu en navegador Firefox sin Ventana Imprimir

Tags: imprimir, tpv

Tengo una aplicación web que es un TPV (Terminal de punto de venta de una tienda) que funciona en Firefox en SO Ubuntu. Esta aplicación imprime tickets, lo que sucede es que cada vez que se le da en la aplicación a imprimir, se abre la típica venta de Imprimir (donde eliges cuantas copias, qué impresora utilizar, etc.). No queremos que se abra esta ventana, sino que directamente imprima el ticket cuando se le da en la aplicación a imprimir.

¿Cómo deshabilitar esa ventana de Ubuntu para que en firefox no se abra esa ventana emergente "Imprimir"? ¿Se debe solucionar en Firefox o en Ubuntu?

Comment: Por favor, añade más información a la pregunta: ¿es una aplicación web? ¿se imprime usando JavaScript?

Comment: Gracias Alvaro por pasarlo aquí. Lo había escrito aquí de nuevo, pero para no duplicarlo la pregunta ya lo he borrado. ¡Gracias! ; )

Comment: Si lo que quieres es imprimir directamente desde el navegador sin el diálogo de impresión: no es posible (al menos no directamente con JavaScript, puede que con algún plugin). Imagina que se permitiese imprimir sin darle la opción al usuario de dar el visto bueno, muchos sitios web imprimirían cosas sin permiso

Comment: Si que se puede. Si ponemos en el navegador Firefox "about:config" sale una lista de comandos para activar y desactivar, pero no se cómo se consigue. Después debe haber un comando llamado "print.always_print_silent" o algo parecido que hay que activar. Print silent hace referencia a imprimir sin ventana emergente. Pero, no consigo que imprima sin ventana emergente, no me hace caso. ¿Cómo se hace?

Comment: Yo utilizo jsPDF(https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). Pero claro tendrías adaptarte a ella y reescribir parte de código.

Answer (score 0):

Como le comentabas a Alvaro, no ibas mal encaminado...

En principio si que "existe" la opción **print.always_print_silent**, pero no está disponible por defecto, si no que deberás crear tú dicha opción.

**Click Derecho** en la página de **about:config** - **New Boolean** - Le damos el nombre de "**print.always_print_silent**" (sin comillas) - Lo seteamos a **true**.

En principio y a no ser que en Quantum lo hayan capado debería funcionar.

Ya nos comentas, un saludo

Comment: Alvaro está en lo cierto en que directamente con Javascript no es posible. ; )

Comment: Efectivamente, y nadie le quita la razón :)

Comment: Como editaste el comentario, no me quedo entonces claro si te sirvió :D. ¿Esta aplicación es para uso interno de tu empresa?, en dicho caso será posible, de lo contrario, no puedes acceder a la configuración por defecto del navegador en este tipo de casos, sería un grave fallo de seguridad. Ten en cuenta que mi respuesta está basada en que es una aplicación de uso propio...

Comment: Cuando lo pueda probar te diré si me funciona, y efectivamente es para uso local, en un terminal concreto de una tienda.